# SSIS- working with files

Tags: file, ssis, task

I'm trying to grab all the files that start with the name Comp based on the file's modified date in a folder (today's date). There are multiple files named Comp1, CompAL, Comp50, etc.
Basically, I have a script task with this code:

```
public void Main()
    {
        DateTime lastModified = DateTime.MinValue;
        string path = Dts.Variables["User::CompFilePath"].Value.ToString() ;
        List<FileInfo> LastFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(file);
            if ((fileinfo.LastWriteTime > lastModified))
            {

                lastModified = fileinfo.LastWriteTime;
                LastFiles.Add(fileinfo);
                Dts.Variables["User::CompFileNames"].Value = fileinfo.ToString();


            }

        }
```

Then, i'm sending myself an email to see if I get all the files, but I only get one file name even that is not even the Comp file, there are around 50 Comp files.

The CompFilePath variable is a string and value is \SharedDrive\work\
the CompFileNames is empty so it can store the file names.

1. How can I add what the file name starts with so it can grab them all?
2. How can I get all the file names instead of just one? Its like my list is only grabbing one file.
3. If I save all the file names in the variable CompFileNames, would I be able to use this as a filespec in the ForEachLoop container?
   I've tried searching online, but I can't find any tutorials regarding this. 
   Can someone please help me or direct me to a tutorial? I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: You haven't explained what you are sending your email based off... but I can see the loop in your code simply replaces the value of the variable `CompFileName` with the file in the loop, replacing it each time. So this variable will contain only the last filename. Have you looked at the For Each File iterator? it will probably do what you want without any code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make `CompFileNames` into a variable that can hold a collection i.e. an `Object` type variable. Next, create a `List<string>` called, say, `FileInfoList` to hold the `fileInfo.ToString()` values that you want to store in `CompFileNames` and populate this `List`. After you have completed processing for each file in the folder, assign `FileInfoList` to `CompFileNames` to populate it.

A variable of `Object` type can be used as an `Enumerator` in a `ForEach` container. You can change the `Enumerator` type to `Foreach From Variable` and use `CompFileNames` as the source variable. Then, create a `String` variable to hold an item from the collection during the looping, called, say `FileInfoName`, and in the `Variables` tab, map index 0 to that variable.